# How to create Sequence diagrams in UMLet for Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, uml, sequence

I found an UML plugin for Eclipse at http://www.umlet.com/ - on the main page, it is written that it is possible to create sequence diagrams, but I didn't found any example and don't know how to create them.
Is it possible to create UML sequence diagrams with this plugin?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Already found - in combobox up possible select type of diagram.

Comment: It should also be noted, that you can mix elements from various pages of the palette in single diagram as you wish.